# Call static member function by pointer

Tags: c++, data-structures, function-pointers

I'm working on a small custom Assembler

I have a vector of struc to storing OPCODE informations (Mnemonic, number and type of argument, parsing function,...)

```
typedef char    args_type_t;

typedef struct  op_s {
    std::string     opcode;
    char            nbr_args;
    args_type_t     type[4];
    int             code;
    Tryte           (*fct)(std::vector<std::string>);
} op_t;
```

the parsing function is pointer on a static member function :

```
{"MOV", 2, {T_REGISTER | T_ADDRESS, T_REGISTER | T_ADDRESS | T_CONSTANT}, 1, &Opcodes::MOV},
```

and the function :

```
class Opcodes
{
public:
    static Tryte Opcodes::MOV(std::vector<std::string> _opMap) {
        return Tryte(0);
    }
};
```

I try this, but I get SEGFAULT (`str()` is a member function of Tryte) :

```
for (int i = 0; i < opMap.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < op_tab.size(); j++) {
        if (!op_tab[j].opcode.compare(opMap[i][2])) {
            std::cout << "OPBYTE : " << op_tab[j].fct(opMap[i]).str() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call my function without instanciate Opcodes object it's posible ?

EDIT :

my error was here : `if (!op_tab[j].opcode.compare(opMap[i][2]))`
my mnemonic is the 1st item n opMap

Comment: Try `(op_tab[j].fct)(opMap[i]).str()`.  The braces are important for grouping, since `fct` is a pointer to a function, not a member function.

Comment: thx, but I found my problem : !op_tab[j].opcode.compare(opMap[i][2]) in my opMap the mnemonic is at place 1 not 2 ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems right, so perhaps a debugger information could help a bit.
But we can try to improve the friendlyness of the code by using a std::function:

```
typedef char    args_type_t;

#include <functional>
typedef struct  op_s {
    std::string     opcode;
    char            nbr_args;
    args_type_t     type[4];
    int             code;
    std::function<Tryte(std::vector<std::string>>)>  fct;
} op_t;
```

As for the sefgault, send us the backtrace.
Also, try to use range-based-for as it doesn't needs to tranverse the map to get the element again (as you are doing inside of the inner loop)

```
for (auto op : opMap) {
    for (auto tab : op_tab) {
        if (!tab.opcode.compare(op[1])) {
            std::cout << "OPBYTE : " << tab.fct(op).str() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

One common fix that you can do to not miss the indexes anymore is to use an Enum holding the possibilities.

```
enum Columns {
    FuncPointer,
    UserData
}

for (auto op : opMap) {
    for (auto tab : op_tab) {
        if (!tab.opcode.compare(op[FuncPointer])) {
            std::cout << "OPBYTE : " << tab.fct(op).str() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```